# How can I stream video from a Raspberry Pi to a webpage?

Tags: stream, iot

I'm currently working on a project that involves taking a webcam and transmitting the feed to a server, but I don't know where to start (I'm completely new to IoT) I'm planning on using a Raspberry Pi to transmit video. I want to, instead of port-forwarding the cam feed, take the feed and stream it to a web page. The web page would have some rudimentary controls to control a toy car (similar to [this](https://sidigital.co/articles/lab-sid/))

How can I stream a Raspberry Pi camera feed to a web page with controls to control a toy car?

Answer (score 4):

You need a middle-man to do the relay job between the Pi and the webpage, on a remote server instance which has a public IP address.

Since you did not mention any enforcements in terms of video quality, responsiveness or encoding, I propose that you take a look at this [video streaming tutorial for the Pi](http://phoboslab.org/log/2013/09/html5-live-video-streaming-via-websockets).

If you'd like to bypass the port-forwarding option, you would need to implement an architecture such as the following.

[image]

Taking the previous tutorial, the `stream-server` will be deployed on an instance on the cloud, awaiting for streams to be sent on port `8082`, and your browser to read the stream from port `8084`.

Comment: Thank you! Even though it's been 3 years since, I spent the past few months working on an implementation for a remote-controlled Roomba over at https://github.com/Itimoto/Roomba-Roamer

Answer (score 0):

Use MJPEG-streamer and connect it with your intermediate server to stream video from device to Web.For more information refer the link https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/stream-video-from-the-raspberry-pi-camera-to-web-browsers-even-on-ios-and-android